# How does Inkscape decide whether to use flowRoot or text?

Tags: text, inkscape, svg

The program for which I'm creating svg doesn't display text that I create in Inkscape where Inkscape saves the text as flowRoot.

When does Inkscape choose to use `svg:flowRoot`?

Is there a way to tell it to convert a field with `svg:flowRoot` into `svg:text`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the inkscape forum:

> Flowed text is created
>
> - when dragging a frame with the text tool before entering the text.
> - when flowing text into a frame (menu 'Text > Flow into Frame')
>
> To convert flowed text into regular text, save a copy of the file and
> use the menu command 'Text > Convert to text' in the copy (to be able
> to edit the flowed text later on in the original if needed

I have confirmed the convert to text works - just make sure you select the text and not a frame for example.

Note that some software, such as Apache's [Batik SVG Toolkit](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), cannot render SVG with `flowRoot` elements. Consequently, any software that uses the Batik library (such as [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)) will also be unable to display the SVG file. The error message from Batik will include a short description about `flowRoot` being the cause of its inability to render the SVG file. Converting the text to text, as described above, should alleviate this issue.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391197/svg-inkscape-generated-file-does-not-show-flowroot-objects-on-browser