# Fitting text into a Letter using inkscape?

Tags: typography, text, inkscape

Can someone please help me figure out how to add text into the shape of a LETTER using *inkscape*? I keep trying and nothing happens. I type out the letter using the text tool, click object to path. Type out my text using the text tool. Select both and then click Flow Into Frame... nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like below, then you're definitely on the right track

- Type the letter and make the font **large**
- Turn the letter into a path (`Path menu > Object to Path`)
- **Ungroup** the result by selecting it and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (even a single letter with no 'holes' is grouped)
- Make the letter object semi-transparent (so you can see the flowed text when you do it)
- Type your words you want to put into the shape and make the font **small**
- Select the letter shape and the text (status bar will say 2 objects of types Path and Text)
- `Text menu > Flow into frame`

I also left and right justified the text to make it adhere to the shape more.

The relative size of the two fonts is critical - as is the ungroup step.

You'll get big vertical gaps unless the words are short enough to fit in the width of the letter - eg the backbone of the F here.

You can download the [svg file](http://www.thinkui.co.uk/examples/f-flow.svg) for this but it won't render in a browser I don't think, as [standard svg won't support flowRoot](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21733/1663) but you can use the Convert to Text option if you need

[image]

Comment: I seriously can't do it : (. I made my letter as large as the page can make it, and I made the font size 8-  nothing! By making the letter transparent, did you mean just changing the opacity to 0%? I'd really like some help, and what you did above is EXACTLY what I am trying to do!

Comment: @Hannah - I think what might be happening is that when you turn text into a path it creates a group, even if there's only one letter. After turning text into a path, ungroup the letter, then select the letter path and the text and flow into frame.

Comment: Okay... I am SO close!! The only thing I can't figure out now is that after my first word I get this HUGE gap where the next word basically starts at the line after. Is it because of my font and that little dip? (arg... I can't figure out how you put attachments on here)

Comment: never mind... that was it!! i did it! i did it!! yayyyy thank you so much Roger! You're the only one who could help!!

Comment: aw, poo... @Roger Attrill... I'm having tousle again!! I'm trying to flow a single word into a shape and when I do all the steps... when I get to the last step nothing happens! The word disappears and all I see is the shape : /, help?

Comment: @Hannah Only the words flow, not the letters, so if the word is too long to fit inside the letter shape you probably won't see it at all.